# What is the use of a play icon with line next to it

Tags: buttons, icons, audio

We got a few general music player icons for playing and manipulating playlists.

```
>  = play tune
>> = hold to move backwards in tune (or skip to next tune)
<< = hold to move forward in tune (or skip to prev tune)
|| = pause
>>| = skip one tune forward and play
<<| = skip one tune back and play
>| = add to the end of queue?
```

The last icon is little bit vague and is not used that much. I thought it meant play tune at end of playlist. I tried to find information of the button on the internet and even if it is used a lot in icon sets there isn't any information on the use of it.

Comment: It's funny how nowadays I automatically assume >>| and <<| (I think usually |<<) means go to end or beginning respectively, given their wide use with pagination controls. I can't remember now, but I'm assuming when I first met pagination I was pressing these icons thinking it would take me to the next page, as it would have taken me to the next track on a CD player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icons are like idioms and its hard to use the ones which are universally understood. I agree that >| doesn't reads like "Add to the end of queue"  [..+] might have meant this more but >| also may mean "Take me to the last item in the list".

Somethings we waste an opportunity of using something which would be generally acceptable and our urge to clarify it actually makes it difficult. Whenever something is added to a stack, it is added either towards the front or towards the end. If you only have one button which reads "Add to the end of queue" and not another one which also says "Add to the start of queue" then why are you creating an opportunity to confuse user. Simply ask him to "Add to queue" and he would expect within the possibilities and eventually learning it fully after use.

Generally as a rule, operations/actions which are not risky shouldn't be over-protected. Adding and removing of songs to the playlist is one of those.